# How to determine the type of contents in an iAd?

Tags: ios, iad

I simply want to add iAds to my app but since my app is specifically designed for families, it's crucial that it's free of any inappropriate contents. 
In Short, how do I include only "safe" contents in my iAds?

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.